# How to exit Meta Mode boot loop?

Tags: recovery-mode, reboot

I have a ZTE Blade V7 Lite, which is stuck in Meta Mode. If I reboot, I can enter Recovery Mode, where I can select some options, e.g. wipe data, but when I select "reboot", it goes Meta Mode (displays "META MODE" in the corner, and no move).

In Meta Mode, I can connect it with ADB, but I can't do anything, because it's unauthorized:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
10799213    unauthorized
```

I just wanted to boot into the normal mode (by using some ADB command) and use the device. It came out after a normal reboot. I've already performed factory reset, but still boots into Meta Mode.